# Combine a serialized object with an existing xml doc and return it?

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-serialization, streamreader

I'm trying to figure out to to combine a serialized object with an existing xml doc and return it as a webservice.

Thanks ahead for you help.

Sample code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetApple()
    {

    Apples apples = Report.GetReport();
    //  this returns:
        //  <Apples xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        //  <Name>Smtih</Name>
        //  <Size>11</Size>
        //  <Weight>111</Weight>
        //  <Color>Red</Color>
        //  </Apples>

    string TemplatePath = Server.MapPath("~/Template.xml");
        // this is:
        // <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        // <applereport>
        //  <moretags>
        //    <july>
        //      <report>
        //        <DATA-GOES-HERE></DATA-GOES-HERE>
        //      </report>
        //    </july>
        //  </moretags>
        // </applereport>

        // Read TemplatePath into a memory stream
        // find the node: <DATA-GOES-HERE></DATA-GOES-HERE>
        // 
        // put serialixed output of Report.GetReport() where <DATA-GOES-HERE></DATA-GOES-HERE> is

        return FullReport;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the object without the namespace and the root and then merge it.

[Serializing without the namespace](http://www.csharper.net/blog/serializing_without_the_namespace__xmlns__xmlns_xsd__xmlns_xsi_.aspx)

Comment: hello, actually it should NOT be a string, but an the  xml/serialized message. I'm just not sure how to do this.

Comment: replaced the answer, got the question wrong, sorry to late to tired. ;)

Comment: Why would you want to serialize without the namespace? If the XML has a namespace, and you don't include it, then you've produced invalid XML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time right now for a full example, but look at the [XPathNavigator.AppendChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163341.aspx) method.

The idea is to get an `XPathNavigator` instance pointing in your document to where you want to add data, then use the `AppendChild` method to produce an `XmlWriter`. Use that `XmlWriter` as the parameter to `XmlSerializer.Serialize`.

You can then return the entire `XmlDocument.DocumentElement` from the web service using the `XmlElement` type as the return type of the `WebMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

for my situation this worked:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

public WebService()
{

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument GetApple()
{

    Apples apples = Report.GetReport();
    //  this returns:
    //  <Apples xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    //  <Name>Smtih</Name>
    //  <Size>11</Size>
    //  <Weight>111</Weight>
    //  <Color>Red</Color>
    //  </Apples>

    // Serialization

    string serializedXML = SerializeObject(apples);



    string TemplatePath = Server.MapPath("~/Template.xml");
    // this is:
    // <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    // <applereport>
    //  <moretags>
    //    <july>
    //      <report>
    //        <DATA-GOES-HERE></DATA-GOES-HERE>
    //      </report>
    //    </july>
    //  </moretags>
    // </applereport>


    // Read TemplatePath into a memory stream
    // find the node: <DATA-GOES-HERE></DATA-GOES-HERE>
    // 
    // put serialixed output of Report.GetReport() where <DATA-GOES-HERE></DATA-GOES-HERE> is
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(TemplatePath);
    XmlNodeList datagoeshere = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("DATA-GOES-HERE");
    if (datagoeshere != null && datagoeshere.Count > 0)
        datagoeshere[0].InnerXml = serializedXML;


    return xdoc;
}
/// <summary>
/// To convert a Byte Array of Unicode values (UTF-8 encoded) to a complete String.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="characters">Unicode Byte Array to be converted to String</param>
/// <returns>String converted from Unicode Byte Array</returns>
private String UTF8ByteArrayToString(Byte[] characters)
{
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    String constructedString = encoding.GetString(characters);
    return (constructedString);
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts the String to UTF8 Byte array and is used in De serialization
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pXmlString"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private Byte[] StringToUTF8ByteArray(String pXmlString)
{
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(pXmlString);
    return byteArray;
}

/// <summary>
/// Method to convert a custom Object to XML string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pObject">Object that is to be serialized to XML</param>
/// <returns>XML string</returns>
public String SerializeObject(Object pObject)
{
    try
    {
        //Create our own namespaces for the output
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

        //Add an empty namespace and empty value
        ns.Add("", "");


        String XmlizedString = null;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Apples));
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriterFormattedNoDeclaration(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, pObject, ns);
        memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
        XmlizedString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        return XmlizedString.Trim();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e);
        return null;
    }
}

public class XmlTextWriterFormattedNoDeclaration : System.Xml.XmlTextWriter
{
    public XmlTextWriterFormattedNoDeclaration(Stream w, Encoding encoding)
        : base(w, encoding)
    {
        Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument() { } // suppress
} }
```

and the response from the webserivce is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<applereport>
  <moretags>
    <july>
      <report>
        <DATA-GOES-HERE>
          <Apples>
  <Name>Smtih</Name>
  <Size>11</Size>

  <Weight>111</Weight>
  <Color>Red</Color>
</Apples>
        </DATA-GOES-HERE>
      </report>
    </july>
  </moretags>
</applereport>
```